# why the difference between firefox/chrome responsive emulation and a smartphone?

Tags: css, responsive-design, google-chrome-devtools, firefox-developer-tools

I'm using Firefox and Chrome to develop a responsive web page. On both browsers, I've changed the css to float an element to the left when the screen size is below 770px. Both of their responsive modes allow me to confirm that it behaves as predicted, floating to the left only below that size.

But when I use my 5 inch (720 x 1280) screen Huawei P8, the element is not floated left.

scss

```
@include bp(max-width, 770px) {
    .products-list .price {
        float: left;
    }
```

css

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 770px)
.products-list .price {
    float: left;
 }
```

html

```
<ul class="products-list">
<li class="items">
    <div class="product-info">
        <div class="left-product">
                <div class="price">
                    <span class="reg-price">
                                        <span class="price">$1000</span>
```

Why would this be?

Comment: Can you show your code?

Comment: Pixel ratio? https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/retina-display-media-query/  - also, what device? Also, are you using any css to ENSURE your media queries fire? (For example, showing / hiding an element at the 770 size, or putting an obvious border in place, etc)?  Lastly - depends on your CSS and markup.  Please reduce it to the relevant bits, not the entire page!

Comment: Which device are you using? To ensure is not a cache problem try inspecting the mobile browser using the Chrome (for android) or Safari (for iOS) built in inspector for mobile devices via usb . This happens to me a lot. When I inspect the device sometimes the page is using old cached stylesheets.

Comment: @LuisRivera yes it was cache-related, thanks, you can post it as a reply and I'll accept it

Comment: Glad it helped! I posted the answer. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To ensure is not a cache problem try inspecting the mobile browser using the Chrome (for android) or Safari (for iOS) built in inspector for mobile devices via usb . This happens to me a lot. When I inspect the device sometimes the page is using old cached stylesheets.

https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/debug/remote-debugging/remote-debugging